# pjs is undefined (processingjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery

if i use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    pjs = Processing.getInstanceById("EyeCanvas");
    console.log(pjs);
}
```

then pjs is always undefined

when i use this:

```
function test() {
    pjs = Processing.getInstanceById("EyeCanvas");
    console.log(pjs);
}
```

and trigger test() with a button then pjs = D.Processing, as it should be.

I load the scripts in this order:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="processing-1.3.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1-7-1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

How can i work with pjs without have people to press a button?

Comment: What happens if you try it in the page's "load" handler instead of "ready"?

Comment: To clarify Pointy's comment: `$(window).load(function() { // Get instance here })`

Comment: Why is processing before jquery? And what browser/platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this - just to also see if it is a timing issue - note the swapped scripts too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1-7-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="processing-1.3.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

var tId,pjs,cnt=0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  tId=setInterval(function() {
    pjs = Processing.getInstanceById("EyeCanvas");
    console.log(cnt+':'+pjs);
    if (pjs) clearInterval(tId);
  },500);
});
```

and what does this say?

```
var tId,pjs,cnt=0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  pjs = Processing.getInstanceById("EyeCanvas");
  console.log(cnt+':'+pjs);
  if (!pjs) tId=setInterval(function() {
    pjs = Processing.getInstanceById("EyeCanvas");
    console.log(cnt+':'+pjs);
    if (pjs) clearInterval(tId);
  },500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes *mplungjan* wrote the true answer, but remember that, when you use JQuery plugins you must  be load JQuery library first, all time.

Comment: So why is this comment accepted when I not only commented it but also swapped the scripts in my answer?